# Criptografia AES JSF

Tags: java, jsf, criptografia, aes

Estou com o Seguinte problema, tenho uma algorítimo de criptografia AES. Quando executo ele pela main funciona, porem quando executo ele em uma pagina jsf e descriptografo o texto ele retorna varias ????? quando contem character especial na String.
Estou usando o inputText do Primefaces 6 para exibir o retorno na tela.

```
 public  String encrypt(String Data, String pKey) throws Exception 
  {
    Key key = generateKey(pKey);
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(Data.getBytes());
    String encryptedValue = new BASE64Encoder().encode(encVal);
    return encryptedValue;
  }

    public String decrypt(String encryptedData, String pKey) throws Exception 
    {
        Key key = generateKey(pKey);
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] decordedValue = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encryptedData);
        byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);
        String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
        return decryptedValue;
    }
```

e abaixo a pagina xhtml

```
<p:outputLabel value="Original Text: "/>
            <p:inputText value="#{criptografiaCtr.texto}"/>
            <p:outputLabel value="Key 16 Bits: "/>
            <p:inputText value="#{criptografiaCtr.chave}"/>
            <p:outputLabel value="Encrypted Text : "/>
            <p:inputText id="textoCri" value="#{criptografiaCtr.textoCriptografado}"/>
            <p:outputLabel value="Decrypted Text: "/>
            <p:inputText id="textoDes" value="#{criptografiaCtr.textoDesCriptografado}"/>
          </p:panelGrid>
          <p:commandButton value="Encryption" >
            <p:ajax event="click" listener="#{criptografiaCtr.criptografar()}" update="textoCri" process="@form"/>
          </p:commandButton> 
          <h:commandButton value="Decrypted">
            <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{criptografiaCtr.descriptografa()}" execute="@form" render="textoDes"/>
          </h:commandButton>
```

Comment: configura o encoding, ex: Data.getBytes("UTF-8") na key também, pode fazer, generateKey(new String(pKey, ""UTF-8))

Comment: @DilneiCunha funcionou certinho, obrigado. Se voce quiser joga como resposta, pois vou marcar como a resposta que resolveu meu problema. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

você precisa configurar o encoding, segue como fazer:

```
Data.getBytes("UTF-8");
generateKey(new String(pKey, ""UTF-8));
```

abraços.